# How can I read multiple lines from a text area using a python API script?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a python script and part of the input I'm getting is a text area. The user inputs a multi-line value and I need to use each line separately. So the input from the user would look something like this:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

And I need to put them each in seperate vars in the python script. How would I go about reading the input line-by-line?

Comment: How do your users input test? Via console or text file or what?

Comment: Please explain how this data looks like: list, dict, string?

Comment: show your code, explain what isn't working

Comment: Do you really need a separate variable for each value? Why don't you make a `list` containing all the values and access each one of them via `listName[i]`?

Comment: Users input text via GUI. No console/file. Data comes from a text area, so I've been assuming string seperated by newlines. I could make it into a list, that's definitely an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the input is a string separated by a new-line character you could use the *splitlines()* method:

```
text = 'value1\nvalue2\nvalue3\nvalue4'
var1, var2, var3, var4 = text.splitlines()
```

This will put them in separate variables but you'll get an error if there's less or more than four lines. Thus it's safer to put it in a list:

```
text = 'value1\nvalue2\nvalue3\nvalue4'
list_of_vars = text.splitlines()
```